# Firebase dynamic link support custom parameters?

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I am writing a App for a Open Source Conference.

Originally each attendees will receive different link via email or SMS like

https://example.com/?token=fccfc8bfa07643a1ca8015cbe74f5f17

then use this link to open app, we can know the user is which attendee by the token.

Firebase release a new feature Dynamic Links in I/O 2016, it provide better experience for users.

I had try that, but I can't find any way to pass the custom parameters (the token) in dynamic links, how to use the same link with different parameters to my users?

Thanks.

Comment: Denny, have you get the solution for this? Same scenario I am facing.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I don't think you can use the short url: 
`https://<my app>.app.goo.gl/Gk3m`
unless you create one for each user, but you can use the long url: 
`https://<my app>.app.goo.gl/?link=https://example.com/?token=fccfc8bfa07643a1ca8015cbe74f5f17 ...(add other parameters as needed)` 
and set new token for each user.

I assume you generate the tokens automatically. In that case you can use [this](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/urlshortener/v1) to shorten the links.

Comment: @diidu how can i use in c#? please help

Comment: @BrijeshMavani I am not expert with C#, but my answer is completely language independent, so you can use it in any language.

Comment: I tried in this way: https://<my app>.app.goo.gl/?link=https://example.com/?name=test?email=test@test.com
This is giving shortlink as https://<my app>.app.goo.gl/abcd, after decoding this short url it is coming like https://<my app>.app.goo.gl/?link=https://example.com/?name=test?email%3Dtest@test.com
%3D is coming in place of = after decoding it.

Comment: How do we change the token from the short url?

Comment: @OliverDixon You don't. You change it on the long url and generate a short one if needed.

Comment: This is my solution for sending/receiving parameters using long url https://stackoverflow.com/a/59436486/2238515

Comment: @diidu Is short url useless in this case?

Comment: @CarlosEduardoKiLee Yes. The one generated at Firebase console is pretty much useless in this case.

Comment: So this is not a Dynamic Link? Seems like Deep Link.

Comment: I don't understand, are we create new dynamic link for each invitation?

Comment: @TahaMalik Hi, so are your create dynamic link for each invitation or you made some custom on it?

Comment: @diidu let say I create dynamic link for e-commerce apps, should I create dynamic link for each product on fierbase console?

Comment: @MNFS It is a while since I worked with dynamic links, some things have changed since then and I may not remember all the details, but I think it depends how you want to use the links. If you want the link to open specific app, you'll need different link for each app. Unless you are happy with Android popping up a list of apps for user to select and that only works with installed apps. There is no way to direct the link to multiple Play store pages.

Comment: Important if you want to pass more than one parameter: You have to encode your parameter list in URL e.g. `param1=123&param2=321` in `param1%3D123%26param2%3D321`. Link: https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/url_encode.html

Answer (score 14):

**1)** From `https://console.firebase.google.com/` (no need for custom parameter here.)

[image]

**2)** Create link somewhere, f.e. on your confluence page (here we add our parameter):

```
https://PROJECTNAME.page.link/?link=https://PROJECTNAME.page.link/LINKNAME?PARAMETER=1&ofl=https://www.PROJECTNAME.com/
```

*PARAMETER* is your custom parameter.

*ofl* is a link where to go if click the link from another platform (PC, Mac).

**3)** Getting link data from android project Kotlin code:

```
Firebase.dynamicLinks
        .getDynamicLink(intent)
        .addOnSuccessListener { pendingDynamicLinkData ->
            val parameter: String =
                pendingDynamicLinkData?.link?.getQueryParameter("PARAMETER").orEmpty()
        }
```

Comment: That did not work for me. Maybe because I am using FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance() instead of Firebase.dynamicLinks?

Comment: They have changed something (firebase guys). 
Now when constructing a link to click use 
LINKNAME?PARAMETER
Instead of
LINKNAME/?PARAMETER

Comment: This worked for me in 2021. Make sure you add your custom params after the inner link, not at the end of the main link: https://<domain>/<path>/?link=https://<domain>/<path>?PARAMETER=VALUE&apn=<appId>

I was adding it after the apn, but apn is a parameter of the outer URL, and PARAMETER should be in the query of the inner URL under "link"

Comment: You can find your long-version dynamic link by clicking the ⋮ menu next to the link on the console, going in Link Details and using your 'Long Dynamic Link'. Add parameters to the inner link and they will come through in the app

Comment: It worth mentioning the source document for this https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-manually

Comment: @AmitP thanks. This page did not exist when I answered this question.

Answer (score 12):

1. Create a dynamic link

   [image]
2. Go to link details

   [image]
3. Copy the *long* dynamic link and add your parameter in the link parameter of the URL, e.g., PARAMETER=132323

   *https://link.projectname.com/?link=https://link.projectname.com/LINK?PARAMETER=132323&apn=com.projectname.app&afl=https://link.projectname.com/LINK*

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: this was the right answer to me (in 2022), you have to pay attention to the whole long link and put your custom parameter at the place of PARAMETER on above URL

Comment: though it does redirect, it did not forward the custom parameters for a web url

Answer (score 8):

If you want to use dynamic links with custom arguments with REST, here is an example of a payload:

```
{
  "dynamicLinkInfo": {
        "dynamicLinkDomain": "example.app.goo.gl",
        "link": "http://someurl.com?my_first_param=test&my_second_param=test2"
  },
  "suffix": {
     "option":"UNGUESSABLE"
    }
}
```

Make sure your remove 'https://' from your dynamicLinkDomain

Julien

Comment: and how do you retrieve it on the receiving side? thanks.

Comment: After decoding the short URL, params afrer & symbol is not coming

Answer (score 6):

Case A. If you want the short link to expand to a link with multiple parameters:

In the part where you setup a dynamic link, any parameter you append to the deep link URL will go on all platforms (web, iOS, android)
[image]

Case B. If you want to use dynamic parameters, you should use the api to create a short link

see [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest)

Comment: But then customParam1 will always be 'abc' when passed to the app. How can this be dynamic?

Comment: @Silas did you find the solution, or know how to achieve dynamic parameters?

Comment: @Silas were you able to achieve dynamic parameters?

Answer (score 5):

Now you can create short links using the Firebase SDK through the `FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().createDynamicLink()`:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/android/create

Sample code:

```
Task shortLinkTask = FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().createDynamicLink()
    .setLink(Uri.parse("https://example.com/"))
    .setDynamicLinkDomain("abc123.app.goo.gl")
    // Set parameters
    // ...
    .buildShortDynamicLink()
    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                // Short link created
                Uri shortLink = task.getResult().getShortLink();
                Uri flowchartLink = task.getResult().getPreviewLink();
            } else {
                // Error
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

1 First Change your Dynamic Link in firebase console from http://exampleandroid/test to http://exampleandroid/test?data 2. You send the query paramter data with this

```
 DynamicLink dynamicLink = FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().createDynamicLink()
                   // .setLink(dynamicLinkUri)
                    .setLink(Uri.parse("http://exampleandroid/test?data=dsads"))
                    .setDomainUriPrefix("https://App_Name.page.link")
                    // Open links with this app on Android
                    .setAndroidParameters(new DynamicLink.AndroidParameters.Builder().build())
                    // Open links with com.example.ios on iOS
                    .setIosParameters(new DynamicLink.IosParameters.Builder("com.appinventiv.ios").build())
                    .buildDynamicLink();

            dynamicLinkUri = dynamicLink.getUri();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add extra parameter to your link to generate Short URL from Firebase.
Here I given example of Short URL generation using Firebase API.
Here ServiceRequestHelper(this).PostCall is my generic class to make API request

```
String url = "https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/shortLinks?key=YOUR_KEY";

    try {
        PackageManager manager = this.getPackageManager();
        PackageInfo info = manager.getPackageInfo(this.getPackageName(), 0);
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject androidInfoObject = new JSONObject();
        androidInfoObject.put("androidPackageName", getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
        androidInfoObject.put("androidMinPackageVersionCode",String.valueOf(info.versionCode));

        JSONObject iosInfoObject = new JSONObject();
        iosInfoObject.put("iosBundleId", "tettares.Test_ID");
        JSONObject dynamicLinkInfoObj = new JSONObject();
        dynamicLinkInfoObj.put("dynamicLinkDomain", "wgv3v.app.goo.gl");
        dynamicLinkInfoObj.put("link", "https://test.in/?UserId=14&UserName=Naveen");  // Pass your extra paramters to here
        dynamicLinkInfoObj.put("androidInfo", androidInfoObject);
        dynamicLinkInfoObj.put("iosInfo", iosInfoObject);

        JSONObject suffixObject = new JSONObject();
        suffixObject.put("option" , "SHORT");
        jsonObject.put("dynamicLinkInfo", dynamicLinkInfoObj);
        jsonObject.put("suffix", suffixObject);

        Log.d("JSON Object : " , jsonObject.toString());

        new ServiceRequestHelper(this).PostCall(url, jsonObject, false, new CallBackJson() {
            @Override
            public void done(JSONObject result) throws JSONException {

                try {
                    if (result.has("shortLink")) {
                        DEEP_LINK_URL = result.getString("shortLink");                                                   }
                } catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });


    } catch (JSONException | PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**In Your Receiving Activity:**

```
boolean autoLaunchDeepLink = false;
    AppInvite.AppInviteApi.getInvitation(mGoogleApiClient, this, autoLaunchDeepLink)
            .setResultCallback(
                    new ResultCallback<AppInviteInvitationResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(@NonNull AppInviteInvitationResult result) {
                            if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                                // Extract deep link from Intent
                                Intent intent = result.getInvitationIntent();
                                String deepLink = AppInviteReferral.getDeepLink(intent);

                                // Handle the deep link. For example, open the linked
                                // content, or apply promotional credit to the user's
                                // account.

                                // [START_EXCLUDE]
                                // Display deep link in the UI
                                Log.d(TAG, "deeplink URL: " + deeplink); // Here you get https://test.in/?UserId=14&UserName=Naveen
                                // [END_EXCLUDE]
                            } else {
                                Log.d(TAG, "getInvitation: no deep link found.");
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried all above but none work. So I think you should change the link `http://example.com/?userid=123`to`http://example.com/userid/123`

Answer (score 0):

No need of all the hustle

1. Don't shorten the url if you want to pass parameters
2. Write the links like this.

   ```
   //APP_CODE is firebase link
   String link = "https://APP_CODE.app.goo.gl/?refferer=" + userId;

   Intent intent = new AppInviteInvitation.IntentBuilder(getString(R.string.invitation_title))
                   .setMessage(getString(R.string.invitation_custom_message)))
                   .setDeepLink(Uri.parse(link))
                   .setCustomImage(Uri.parse(getString(R.string.invitation_custom_image)))
                   .setCallToActionText(getString(R.string.invitation_cta))
                   .build();

   startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_INVITE);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

For web apps, which generating dynamic links..

```
const data = {
  dynamicLinkInfo: {
    domainUriPrefix: 'subdomain.page.link',
    link: url,
  },
  suffix: {
    option: 'SHORT'
  }
};
return fetch(`https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/shortLinks?key=${environment.firebaseConfig.apiKey}`, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(data),
}).then(res => res.json()).then(response => response.shortLink).catch(console.error);
```