# Android - How to Pull Data From a Dynamic Link

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, firebase-invites

I am using Firebase Dynamic Links and Invitations to invite players to my app. The ultimate goal is for the shared link to contain a unique Table ID that will pull the player directly into the table their friend is currently in.

So far, I can invite players to the app just fine. Open the link, it opens the app, everything is working there.

But I can't for the life of me figure out how to attach/parse the tableID to/from the link to use it.

Most of the documentation I've read glosses over this point, assuming I know how to do it. It's probably something super simple, but I've been chasing this rabbit for two days, and now I'm too far down the rabbit hole to see clearly anymore. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Related question with answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49826185/4815718

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add parameter to Firebase Dynamic Links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49826185/add-parameter-to-firebase-dynamic-links)

Comment: So, if a User installed the Application using the dynamic Link through Playstore and then close the PlayStore and then open the App from the Menu then the dynamic data will be intact or not? Will I be able to detect the referrer? The extras won't get cleared if the Other user doesn't open the App from the PlayStore.