# Android firebase dynamic link

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I have created a dynamic link in firebase console, this dynamic link points to an app in Play Store (i.e. I use this link to share this app with other users via WhatsApp). Also I receive the deep link in my app through getDynamicLink method.

When I append a query parameter(`?invite=494556`) to dynamic link the Play Store page appears but I cannot receive the deep link in `getDynamic` link method it's null. How to do I append query parameters to dynamic link and recieve it when is installed?

I cannot use firebase invite as I want to share via WhatsApp.

Comment: can add code related to how you are retrieving parameter in app?

Comment: I use https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/android/receive.For plain dynamiclink I get deep link but for dynamic link with query parameter pendingDynamicLinkData is null

Comment: I think this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49829041/6021469

Answer (score 0):

In the `getDynamicLink()` success listener of Firebase we get the deeplink url and means we get the data which we put in deeplink url while creating dynamic link from the firebase console. So in your case, you need to provide  `data(invite=494556)` in the deeplink url like this: `https://INVITE/494556`. On the app side you can listen for the string "INVITE" and, whenever your deeplink url contains this string, it means the number at first index is what you are looking for. You can implement different deeplinks in this way, you need to just change the string and provide whichever data you need.