# Do I need to manually create a dynamic link for every product in the e-commerce app while using firebase dynamic link?

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I am using a firebase deep link for my e-commerce application. I am able to create a dynamic link from the console and add a deep link with extra parameters to it. But those parameters are hardcoded.

I can see from the docs that we can create dynamic links using API and SDK. It is suggested in the docs to create a new one every time.

Also, dynamic links created using API or SDK does not show up in the console.

Is there any way to keep the dynamic link same and pass the parameters to it?

I am planning to use the dynamic links in conjunction with the notification. I want to use dynamic links to deep link the notification to a specific screen.

Is there a way to add the extra parameters(e.g. order_id or product_id) to the dynamic link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since each of your products is unique, each of them will need a unique dynamic link.

If you want to pass custom values, you typically encode them into the URL as shown here: [Add parameter to Firebase Dynamic Links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49826185/add-parameter-to-firebase-dynamic-links).

For example, if you use the ["manually" create URLs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-manually#parameters) you pass in the `link` parameter of your choice and that would contain your product ID:

```
https://your_subdomain.page.link/?link=https://www.example.com/product1234&apn=package_name[&amv=minimum_version][&afl=fallback_link]
```

Note: I put "manually" in quotes there, since building URLs this way is highly automatable; it is just more explicit than the using the API to build the URL.